# Ubuntu/Windwos dual boot error: This computer has only 0 bytes disk space remaining

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to add Ubuntu as my second OS to existing Windows 10 on my brand new laptop (dual boot).

I used a ISO-based USB created with Rufus 2.10. However, every time when I try to install Ubuntu it crashes and returns "this computer has only 0 bytes disk space remaining". It crashes at random moment every time.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Any idea on what may cause this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe because the location you chose to install it `only 0 bytes disk space remaining`!

Comment: If your laptop is brand new, its disc will be fully partitioned. You will need to make room for Linux by deleting or shrinking one of the configured partitions. Sometimes manufacturers create two equal partitions (`C:` and `D:`), and if `D:` is empty you can delete this. Otherwise, if there is a single, large `C:` with some auxiliary partitions of 30GB or less, you should shrink this to something like half its size, but preferably 100GB at least: use Windows Disc Management to do this.

Comment: I have created an empty partition for Ubuntu (shrank the existing one).

Comment: @Stan:  We can not guess the mistake you did and it doesn't make sense that the comments you receive for clarification are longer than the information you provide.  What partition did you choose for installation?  Can you show us a list of your partitions?  Did you choose to format it during the installation?

Comment: Did you try to create a partition with the unused space?

Comment: Yes, I did. I have attached some screenshots for more details.

Comment: That screen shot shows 397GB of unallocated space on the drive, which you should probably put on a partition and use for your installation.